# How to get collection object from custom query result in pagination

Tags: magento-1.9, pagination

I have created a custom table in my magento store and wants to show its data on frontend.

For this I have created a block file in my custom module like :

```
class Custom_Module_Block_Pagination extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
        $readConnection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
        $rows = $readConnection->fetchAll('Select * from customer_table where c_id = '.$customer->getId().'');

        $collection = new Varien_Data_Collection();
        foreach($rows as $row){
            $rowObj = new Varien_Object();
            $rowObj->setData($row);
            $collection->addItem($rowObj);
        }
        $this->setCollection($collection);


        /* // this collection works perfect with pagination 
        $collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        */
    }

     protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', 'custom.pager');
        $pager->setAvailableLimit(array(10=>10,20=>20));
        $pager->setCollection($this->getCollection());
        $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
        $this->getCollection()->load();
        return $this;
    }

    public function getToolbarHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
    }
}
```

On frontend the collection not working with pagination.

For example : the collection return `43` rows and pagination showing number of 5 pages in toolbar with `Row per page is 10`  but collection showing all `43 rows` on all pages. but it should showing only `10 rows` on all pages.

Why this is happened? How to resolve this?

**EDIT :** 
My template file :

```
$collection = $this->getCollection();
echo $this->getToolbarHtml();
foreach($collection as $row)
{
    // here tables's tbody
}
```

Comment: please show your phtml file too.

Comment: Please check my edited question.

Comment: You can get help here : http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/18/magento-collection-paging/

Answer (score 4):

The issue is related to Magento's `Varien_Data_Collection` It does not support pagination. As you can see an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8942363/1409718) and also a possible solution [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/447#issuecomment-145534464)
 You can always use a Model for getting collection.
**EDIT**
One more [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20741698/1409718) to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Here i tell what is scenario here you add adding the total collection to pager block.

```
public function __construct()
  {
     $this->setCollection($collection);
  }
```

also set the pager configuration and pager block too

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    parent::_prepareLayout();
    $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', 'custom.pager');
    $pager->setAvailableLimit(array(10=>10,20=>20));
    $pager->setCollection($this->getCollection());
    $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
    $this->getCollection()->load();
    return $this;
}
```

and getting the pager block too

```
public function getToolbarHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
    }
```

but here you missed the  collection with limits

```
public function getCusCollection()
{
  //get values of current page
    $page=($this->getRequest()->getParam('p'))? $this->getRequest()->getParam('p') : 1;
//get values of current limit
    $pageSize=($this->getRequest()->getParam('limit'))? $this->getRequest()->getParam('limit') : 5;
    $offset = ($page - 1) * $pageSize;


    $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    $readConnection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
    $rows = $readConnection->fetchAll('Select * from customer_table where c_id = '.$customer->getId().' LIMIT '.$offset.','.$pageSize.'');

    $collection = new Varien_Data_Collection();
    foreach($rows as $row){
        $rowObj = new Varien_Object();
        $rowObj->setData($row);
        $collection->addItem($rowObj);
    }
    return $collection;
}
```

in your phtml file you call the filtered collection

```
 $collection = $this->getCusCollection();
echo $this->getToolbarHtml();
foreach($collection as $row)
{
    // here tables's tbody
}
```